# Could dark matter be just a gravitational effect of dark energy?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I'm wondering if we just looking at the two sides of the same coin and if there is actually a correlation of DM with DE?

Is it possible that DM just to be a gravitational effect (or an effect that mimics classical gravity) of DE?

Both seem to interact with normal matter in our visible Universe via gravity. Normal gravity for DM and an effective negative gravity for DE (i.e. Cosmological Constant) that leads to the observed accelerated expansion of our Universe?

But isn't possible Dark Energy to have also an effective normal gravitational component (positive gravity) at the same time that we conceive as dark matter gravity?

Maybe the elusive Dark Matter particle is just the possible hidden Dark Energy particle.

[image: Ice crystallization of water]

image source: https://tinyurl.com/yb37euaa

Comment: As far as I am aware, dark energies density is time and spacial invariant. Whereas dark matter is not.

Comment: @jensenpaull This is resolved in some of these theories by decoupling the cosmological constant from the vacuum energy.

Comment: The idea of a dark fluid of negative mass unifying dark energy with dark matter  as a viable candidate for both phenomena: WP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_fluid  https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2018/12/aa32898-18/aa32898-18.html  , video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlLyw2VEDu4

Comment: There is a model that explains dark energy and dark matter as one gravitational potential energy. In this model, dark matter is explained as the gravitational self-energy of galaxies or galaxy clusters, and dark energy is explained as the gravitational potential energy of the observable universe. (Refer to 11~29P) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/359329109

Comment: Regarding the model explaining dark matter and dark energy with negative mass, please also refer to the following paper. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324525352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that DM just to be a gravitational effect (or an effect that mimics classical gravity) of DE?

If you think about galaxies or cluster of galaxies, the DM is the what actually holds them together. If DM had an effect of counter acting the gravitational pull, then the galaxies would not have been formed. In order to explain the galaxy formation and accelerated expansion of the universe at the same time, you need to propose [dark fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_fluid).

There are also some theories where DE and DM interacts.

These theories seems nice but they are just theories and we know nothing about DE and DM. In LCDM cosmology we assume DE and DM do not interact at all.